# Connect to openwrt through router

Tags: bridge, openwrt, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I have a raspberry pi on which I have a working openwrt installation and i can connect to it either directly via Ethernet or through my Netgear router which is further connected to my desktop  through Ethernet

Problem I'm facing is that

1) after I connect my raspberry to Netgear router it suddenly starts sending me to openwrt page with default gateway ip (even though I'm not directly connected to raspberry)
2) the moment I switch on my Router my internet stops working (I have a usb wifi dongle through which I connect to another wifi router)

My objective is to enable the openwrt on raspberry to be able to take internet through its Ethernet port from Netgear router which is further connected with my desktop through Ethernet which is further connected with another router through wifi dongle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps further explanation will shed some light on this. I'm not sure whether you are aware but openWRT is a router, you say you have a Netgear router you are connecting to then another over Wi-Fi. Having more than one router can have consequences when not setup correctly. Enterprise routers will mostly allow you to configure multiple in an environment, but most managed switches can handle this process now.

With that being said a few things could be happening.

1. You can't have two DHCP servers running on the same network - they will knock each other out. So check and see what the IP addresses are on all your devices for the LAN. Make sure they are all on the same subnet (it doesn't sound like you are using VLAN's).
2. Check your DNS settings. If you don't have DNS setup you can use 8.8.8.8 to use Google's or 75.75.76.76 to use Comcast's.
3. Typically with network equipment that will be handling traffic, static addresses work best. They will not change after you create settings such as routes or port forwards. You will want these addresses to be outside of the DHCP range so that other devices won't get assigned the static IPs and cause a conflict.

I hope this helps lead you in the right direction. You may want to edit openWRT configs with terminal rather than the GUI as I've seen it corrupt things from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, yes I missed the DHCP part, I will work on it and will share the results with here, however can u help me understand how could openwrt took over Netgear router even though openwrt is not directly connected to my desktop(openwrt is connected to my Router and that Netgear router is further connected to my desktop)

Comment: You should spend some time to properly format this answer.

Comment: @user378555 Can you post the IP structure that you are using for your network and devices? What is the IP of your router, PC, and Pi?